# Parity warp sync termination on Ropsten

Tags: parity, testnets, ropsten

With the newest version of Parity (1.7.2beta), I cannot finish the warp sync process for Ropsten testnet. After getting nearly all the snapshots, getting this error:

```
2017-09-23 21:17:09  Syncing snapshot 264/272        #0    9/25 peers   8 KiB chain 111 KiB db 0 bytes queue 10 KiB sync  RPC:  1 conn,  1 req/s,  44 µs
2017-09-23 21:17:14  Encountered error during block restoration: RlpIsTooShort
```

After that, a no-wrap sync is started. Any ideas?

Running command is: `parity --geth --chain ropsten --force-ui`

Comment: It's probably a node giving you an invalid snapshot (forked node).